# How to access parent host service while building docker image?

Tags: docker, npm

while building a docker image I would like to access a service hosted on the parent host. For instance, suppose I need to access a `npm` private repository that's running on the host machine `xpto:8080`. On xpto I'm also building a new image that on Dockerfile calls

```
RUN npm set registry http://xpto:8080
RUN npm install
```

When I try to `docker build -t=my_image .` I always get

> failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.168.2.103:4873

Also tried `RUN wget xpto:8080` and got

> failed: No route to host.

Tried to use the --add-host parameter but it didn't workout.

The strange part is that when I try to access the parent host service from another container it runs ok, but had to add the --net="host" parameter like this:

```
docker run --it --rm --net="host" my-test-image sh
wget xpto:8080
```

The thing is that this --net parameter isn't supported by docker build!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For some, unknown reason, the centosOS firewall was only blocking the connection while building and not while running.

The solution was to add an exception to the firewall and problem was solved.